# Redirect on link button does not work - first page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I am using one link button in page to redirect to another page; but when it is redirecting it to another page, the first page is getting reloaded in asp.net.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkIncident" Text="Incidents" runat="server" Style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Verdana; color: White; font-weight: bold;"></asp:LinkButton>
```

javascript:

```
function cellClickpopup(columnName, process) {
  document.getElementById("<%=hdnColumnNamepopupdisplay.ClientID %>").value = "";
  document.getElementById("<%=hdnColumnNamepopupdisplay.ClientID %>").value = columnName;
  document.getElementById("<%=hdnMainprocess.ClientID %>").value = "";
  document.getElementById("<%=hdnMainprocess.ClientID %>").value = process;
  // document.getElementById("<%=hdnValue.ClientID %>").value = dataexist;
  document.getElementById("<%=btnShowPopUpDetails.ClientID %>").click();
  return false;
}
```

in code behind file:

```
lnkIncident.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("cellClickpopup(\"{0}\",\"{1}\");return false;", lnkIncident.Text + "," + "xyz", "ABC"));
```

Comment: I dont want first page to be reloaded

Comment: Please format your question and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have made some edits to the question: reformatted the code, included the title as an introductory paragraph, and used a new more concise title